# How to make global value for URL->bstrVal?

Tags: visual-c++

I am currently using this function inside my program.

```
void CBar::DocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *URL)
```

How to make the BSTR value inside `URL->bstrVal` available for the whole program? I need to access the url value from other function.

Comment: Are you saying you want to copy URL->bstrVal into a global, and you don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you *use* this function (call it), you have the URL and can access the bstrVal member.